# How can I upload an image file using multipart/form-data?

Tags: files, 8

I want to send an image file using REST API in Drupal 8 along with a registration form. I have built a custom API to save the registration form.

For the files I have created another API to save data using HEADERS Content-Type: multipart/form-data and update the registration form with file ID after saving it.

When I send the file using the POSTMAN Chrome extension to check the API, I don't get the file data in `$request->files->get('image_name')` in my Controller. What may be the reason?

Comment: As I know, right now it's not possible. You can upload files as base_64. Discussion is here https://www.drupal.org/node/1927648